# Joining in NoSQL to get chat messages for a user

Tags: mongodb, nosql, cassandra

In my chat app i have private / group chats and I need to get messages for a user.

Let me first explain the whole system.

**Messages:**

```
// group message
{
  id: 1,
  text: 'hello',
  chat_id: 'AjK954_e5iP',
  created_at: 137615...
},

// private message
{
  id: 2,
  text: ':)',
  chat_id: 'Bho9Sr_f51Rz',
  created_at: 137622...
}
```

**Chats:**

```
{
  id: 'AjK954_e5iP',
  type: 'group',
  title: 'My Group yay'
},
{
  id: 'Bho9Sr_f51Rz',
  type: 'private',
  participants: ['A', 'B']
}
```

**Members:**
When we join a group / private chat a new record is created in a table called `members`.

```
// group chat member
{
  user_id: 'A',
  chat_id: 'AjK954_e5iP',
  type: 'group'
}

// private chat member
{
  user_id: 'A',
  chat_id: 'Bho9Sr_f51Rz',
  type: 'private'
}
```

### The Problem

to get the messages i need to perform a join on `members` and `messages` but it's not possible in NoSQL. i could solve the problem for private chats but for group chats an inner join is required.

**SQL way:**

```sql
SELECT messages.* from `members`
    INNER JOIN `messages`.`chat_id` = `members`.`chat_id`
         WHERE `members`.`user_id` = 'A'
```

### Bad solution

If there are thousands of chat_ids, doing a `where in` is slow.

```js
// Pseudocode

chat_ids = Members.where('user_id', 'A').get(['chat_id']);
chat_ids = chat_ids.map(item => item.chat_id);

messages = Messages.whereIn('chat_id', chat_ids).orderBy('created_at').limit(20).get();
```

Comment: Your tags make your question unclear currently. What database system does your data currently live in for where you're trying to achieve your goal? MySQL, MongoDB, and Cassandra are each different and unrelated database systems.

Comment: @J.D. well yes, I haven't chosen which database but if there's a solution i think works for most of them, Here's a simplified version of the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816066/get-chats-list-mongodb

Comment: The implementation of the solution is going to vary from one database system to another, so you'd have to pick a database system first, then a solution to your problem can be provided. If you need to do complex joins and filtering, then *typically* a relational database management system is going to be a better choice than a NoSQL solution. So of the 3 tags you listed, MySQL would be the only applicable choice if you wanted to go that route. PostgreSQL is another free (if that's part of your criteria for choosing a system) RDBMS that's very powerful too.

Comment: @J.D. I'm a RDBMS person the project is easy that way, But can relational databases handle millions of messages every day? i could also go with 2 databases but updating multiple records in 2 database at the same time without transaction is another story.

Comment: I've worked with tables that individually have had 10s of billions of records in them at one time, and were multi-terabytes big, on hardware that the average laptop has nowadays, and was able to query them for results in sub-second time, in a relational database (Microsoft SQL Server). So yes, they can. There's no performance differences between NoSQL and a RDBMS, and anyone who tells you otherwise likely doesn't have a firm understanding on how either works or is biased.

Comment: @J.D. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a MongoDB noob, but does this do what you want?

```
db.members.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      user_id: "A"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "messages",
      "localField": "chat_id",
      "foreignField": "chat_id",
      "as": "thechats"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$thechats"
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$thechats"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      created_at: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 20
  }
])
```

Try it at [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u8854tctPt6).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but MongoDB's lookup isn't for sharded collections. "Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing."

Comment: Oh, I didn't see a mention of a sharded collection.  I guess you'll need to do something at the application level then.

Comment: Yes but it's a bad solution. Building a dedicated database is more efficient!

Comment: FYI, ["In Atlas Data Lake, you can use $lookup to join sharded and unsharded collections from the same database or different databases from Atlas, AWS S3, and HTTP or HTTPS data stores."](https://docs.mongodb.com/datalake/reference/pipeline/lookup-stage/)